# MVC 4 - after seeding database webpages_Roles is still empty

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

So I have basic MVC 4 Internet application project with Entity Framework 5.

I have configured WebSecurity that uses my table for users.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "Id", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Then in my migration configuration class I seed DB with new roles and add users to them.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Infrastructure.KlepecV2Db>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Infrastructure.KlepecV2Db context)
    {
        if(!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }
        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Test1"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Test1");
        }
        if(Membership.GetUser("user1") != null)
        {
            if(!Roles.IsUserInRole("user1","Admin"))
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole("user1", "Admin");
            }
        }
        if (Membership.GetUser("user2") != null)
        {
            if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("user2", "Admin"))
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole("user2", "Admin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I type "update-database" in NuGet console everything gets executed without errors. But if I look into webpages_Roles table its empty. Also webpages_UsersInRoles is empty.

For testing I have removed Role.RoleExists() calls and updating database fails, becouse roles already exists.

What am I missing here? Where are this roles stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across into an error `The Role Manager feature has not been enabled` mentioned by @Magnus. Hope this probably related to your roles issue in which the default role provider is unknown.

The error `The Role Manager feature has not been enabled` happened when I **move** the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` method **from MVC project into a class library** (data access) for code first migration seed.

**The point is `App.config` need to be configured for Package Manager `Update-Database` command to be run just like when `Web.config` exist.**

Below is my `App.config` and `Seed`. Note that

1. <s>I add `"DefaultConnection"` connection string</s> *
2. Add `system.web->roleManager` to set the `enable="true"`
3. Add `runtime->assemblyBinding->qualifyAssembly` to give hint to compiler where is `WebMatrix.WebData` by giving the full assembly name.

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db;Persist Security Info=True;User=user;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="simple">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <qualifyAssembly partialName="WebMatrix.WebData" fullName="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Seed Method:

```
protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "Id", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);

    if(!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
    }
    if (!Roles.RoleExists("Test1"))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Test1");
    }
    if(Membership.GetUser("user1") != null)
    {
        if(!Roles.IsUserInRole("user1","Admin"))
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole("user1", "Admin");
        }
    }
    if (Membership.GetUser("user2") != null)
    {
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("user2", "Admin"))
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole("user2", "Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help anyone with `The Role Manager feature has not been enabled` issue when using code first migration seed in a class library.

### **Update**

`*` EF5 will read the connection string in Web.config of Mvc project but not in the App.config of the project with EF Migrations. However the `membership` and `roleManager` settings is still required in the EF Migration project.

Comment: Hi,  I am experiencing the same issue when trying to run InitializeDatabaseConnection() on my EF migration project.   I have the same settings in App.config and we keep getting the error.   Any ideas ?

Comment: Did your App.config you mention is inside your migration project? What is the error?

Comment: I have the same issue. The error that i get is: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.

Comment: I had this problem after I split out my entity models into a new Data project. Once I added these above example into my *Start-Up Project* (which happened to be a new console app for testing some reporting features) I was able to run my migrations again. What confused me (like others I suspect) this config needs to exist in whatever you have set as your *start-up project*. Having this config only in the data project won't work if you start up from another project. Which is lame because the Migrate-Database doesn't respect the Default Project dropdown in the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add my $0.02 to the conversation. I have a similar setup to CallMeLaNN, but was still getting the error. My solution was to set my "Data" project to a StartUp project. After that, my app.config file started getting picked up, and I can now seed my users from the `Update-Database` command.